# CSS not updating in Production Mode

Tags: magento2.2.7

**Issue**

It doesn't appear that my **merged/minified files** are being updated when changed whilst in **Production Mode**. For example, I made a change to this file:

`app/design/frontend/Theme/theme_child/web/css/styles.css`

But even after I run the following, the styling isn't taking effect:

```
bin/magento setup:di:compile
bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_GB en_US
bin/magento cache:flush
```

I even hit the **Flush Javascript/CSS Cache** button on the backend.

**Question**

Am I missing a step? Is this a known "gremlin"? Could some of the cached files not be clearing as expected? What folder can I `rm -rf` to manually purge them so they can be re-deployed?

**Notes:**

- The changes do take affect on my Dev Server
- It's not my browsers cache
- I'm not using a CDN

Answer (score 0):

You can run this:

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/* pub/static/frontend/* generated/code/*
```

Maybe another cache like Varnish?
After your command you should see changes maybe try change styling in _theme.less its alwayes loaded last one , maybe changes from style.less was overrided by different file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to :

1. clean the **content** of `pub/static/` without the `.htaccess`, once again the content and NOT the folder.
2. `php bin/magento c:c && php bin/magento c:f`. `//cache:clean and cache:flush`
3. `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
4. clean the browser cache.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

you can run the production mode set command again.

```
bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```